# Read data from JSON array to datasource

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have following data from a JSON file that I would like to add as a Datasource for a Combobox in a form:

```
  "opr": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "code": "JS"
    },
    {
      "name": "Diana",
      "code": "DC"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cashier",
      "code": "CS"
    }
  ],
```

"name" is a string that I'd like to display in the form, whereas "code" is the contained value to each name (say if I pick John, then "JS" will display in another text box")

Here's the class I'm going to use:

```
Public Class Opr
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property code As String
End Class

Public Class cgOpr
    Public Property opr As Opr()
End Class
```

Previously I've used For Each to iterate through all IDs and add them with Items.Add, but I wonder if I can use Datasource for this. To my understanding I need to convert the array to a list but I haven't figured out how.

I'm using JSON.NET for parser. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I left out my question... I'm looking for a way to fill those JSON data to a combobox with DataSource (previously I used For Each). I thought I need to convert the array to a list that can be put into DataSource but I have found out a way for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array as datasource too.

```
Dim data As cgOpr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of cgOpr)(jsonString)

combobox.ValueMember = "code"
combobox.DisplayMember = "name"
combobox.DataSource = data.opr
```

Then you can use `combobox.SelectedItem` or `combobox.SelectedValue` for accessing selected data

```
Dim selected As Opr = DirectCast(combobox.SelectedItem, Opr)
Dim selectedCode As String = selected.code

' Or
Dim selectedCode As String = combobox.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

Comment: Thank you! So if there are lots of combo boxes, do I need to set those value and display member by each one?

Comment: If you want use different values for displaying text and for value itself, then yes.